# Leibniz' Law and that good old riddle

Tags: logic, philosophy, paradoxes

There exists a *Theory of Identity* in mathematical logic. I've encountered
it for the first time in
[Principia Mathematica](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principia_Mathematica)
by Alfred North Whitehead and Bertrand Russell (1910).
Quote: "This definition states that $x$ and $y$ are to be called identical when
every predicative function satisfied by $x$ is also satisfied by $y$".
 
Many contemporary philosophers call the principle which expresses this view
"Leibniz' Law".
One particularly explicit statement can be found in
*Introduction to Logic and to the Methodology of Deductive Sciences* by
[Alfred Tarski](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alfred_Tarski).
In chapter III, *On the Theory of Identity*, it is read that
"Among logical laws which involve the concept of identity, the most fundamental
is the following: *$x = y$ if, and only if, $x$ and $y$ have every property in
common*. This law was first stated by Leibniz (although in somewhat different terms)."
Tarski does not provide a reference to the place where, according to
him, Leibniz stated that law. Further refinements can be found on the
[Internet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_of_indiscernibles).
But, for our purpose, it is sufficient to stick to the original definition,
as given with the *Theory of Identity* by Tarski / Russell and Whitehead:
$$
 (x = y) :\Longleftrightarrow
 \left[\;\forall P : P(x) \Longleftrightarrow P(y) \;\right]
$$
Where $:\Longleftrightarrow$ means: logically equivalent by definition.
Let's try something with that definition. *Every* property
in common, they said. We take that quite literally and have, for example:
$$
  P(x) :\Longleftrightarrow
  ( x \, \mbox{is on the left of the} \, "=" \, \mbox{sign} )
$$
With this property in mind, consider the expression:
$$
    1 = 1
$$
Then we see that the $1$ on the right in $1 = 1$ is not on the left, hence the
property $P(1)$ as defined does not hold for that one. Consequently: $1 \ne 1$.
We have run into a paradox.
Oh, you should say, but self-referential properties are of course not allowed.
Sure, I am the last one to disagree with you. This highly artificial example
stresses an important point, though:

- With Leibniz's Law, almost any but *not all* properties are in common

The numerosity of these (not self-referential) properties can still be infinite.
Let $A$ be a set of properties $P_k$ and let's call $A$ the *aspect* or
*scope* of the equality (- anybody who knows a better name ? You're quite welcome ! -):
$$
   A := \left\{ \; P_0(x), P_1(x), P_2(x), \cdots , P_n(x) \; \cdots \right\}
$$
Then ($x = y$) shall be pronounced as *$x$ is equal to $y$ with respect to
$A$*, and may optionally be written as:
$$
 (x \stackrel{A}{=} y) :\Longleftrightarrow
 \left[\;\forall P_k \in A : P_k(x) \Longleftrightarrow P_k(y) \;\right]
$$
It's a matter of routine to prove that common properties of equality (reflexive,
symmetric, transitive) are not different with the above modified definition:
$$
  x \stackrel{A}{=} x \\
  (x \stackrel{A}{=} y) \Longrightarrow (y \stackrel{A}{=} x) \\
  ((x \stackrel{A}{=} y) \wedge (y \stackrel{A}{=} z))
  \Longrightarrow (x \stackrel{A}{=} z)
$$
Up to now, we have not been very clear about what sort of properties one should
have in mind, when comparing object $x$ with object $y$ in some respect $A$.
Therefore consider the decimal representation of numbers and define the following properties:
$$
  P_{c,k}(x) \; :\Longleftrightarrow \; 
  \mbox{" cipher at position $k$ in the decimal representation of $x$ is $c$ "} \\
  \mbox{where} \quad c \in \{0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9\}
$$
We have the two (in)famous numbers, as announced in the header:
$$
    1.000... \quad \mbox{and} \quad 0.999...
$$
Indeed, there exist numerous proofs of the following statement ( e.g. 
[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/0.999...) ) :
$$
    1.000... = 0.999...
$$
However, the following statement is easy to prove now as well. So we have run into some sort of a paradox:
$$
   \neg \left[1.000... \stackrel{A}{=} 0.999... \right]
$$
This raises some obvious **Questions.**
Maybe "common" equality in mathematics is not Leibniz' equality ?
But how can that be?
Hasn't equality been rigorously defined with Russel's / Tarski's
*Theory of Identity* ?
Or maybe, is there a difference between *identity* and *equality* in mathematics ?
Should $\equiv$ and $\stackrel{A}{=}$ be identified
perhaps ? And is the following statement true then:
$$
   1.000... = 0.999... \qquad \mbox{but} \qquad 1.000... \not \equiv 0.999...
$$

Comment: The boring but short resolution is "the" decimal representation of a real number does not exist. Some real numbers have more than one.

Comment: Are you sure that you are not mixing two different concepts ? When you consider decimal representation of real numbers, you are speaking of : 1) rational numbers approximating the real number : in this case 1.000 and 0.999 are different rational numbers; 2) two names for the same object (the real number 1) : in this case you are dealing with names as string of symbols of infinite lenght, that are not so "standard".

Comment: @DanielFischer: To my defense, what's wrong with being confused about a piece of mathematical logic, called the _Theory of Identity_? Honestly, I know what numbers are (take a look at my profile, if you don't believe it). But I don't understand how Leibniz' equality could possibly fit into that mental picture.

Comment: Nothing wrong with being confused by it, @Han. It _is_ confusing.

Comment: Being "on the left side of the equal sign" is not a well-defined property of an object.

Comment: @TimSeguine: You're quite right, but what else is a "well-defined property of an object" with Leibniz' Law?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure that you are not mixing two different concepts ? When you consider decimal representation of real numbers, you are speaking of :

1) rational numbers approximating the real number : in this case $1.000$ and $0.999$ are different rational numbers

2) two names for the same object (the real number $1$) : in this case you are dealing with *names* as string of symbols of infinite lenght, that are not so "standard".

*Added Dec,17.*

I think that there are different aspects regarding *identity*.

1) From a **mathematical** point of view, *equality* is not defined; it is assumed. We simply know what equality between numbers, triangles, etc. are.

2) In **mathematical logic**, first-order logic (see *Wikipedia*) :

> includes the equality symbol as a primitive logical symbol which is always interpreted as the real equality relation between members of the domain of discourse, such that the "two" given members are the same member. This approach also adds certain axioms about equality These equality axioms are:
>
> 1.Reflexivity.
>
> 2.Substitution for functions.
>
> 3.Substitution for formulas.
>
> Many other properties of equality are consequences of the axioms above, for example: symmetry and transitivity.

In second-order logic, the insight of Russell, etc, was that, assuming a formal counterpart of Leibniz's principle, it was possible to derive the aforesaid basic properties of equality. *Is this a definition of identity* ?

3) And now we have the **philosophical** issue : what is identity ? According to Quine, second (and higher)-order logic is deeply involved with "ontological committments". So we can hardly say that its definition of *equality* has answered the philosophical issues related with identity.

*Added Dec,17 - part 2*

You can read some useful comments in *S.C.Kleene*, **Mathematical Logic** (1967) , pag.163 :

> In second-order predicate calculus, we can regard $x=y$ as an abbreviation for $\forall P(P(x) \leftrightarrow  P(y))$, instead of introducing it as a primitive predicate. Since conceptually the idea of equality underlies *our* notion of a domain and of predicates over the domain, it seems more elementary and direct to introduce equality as we do than to define it by refernce to all predicates.

You can see also *Derek Goldrei*, **Propositional and Predicate Calculus** (Springer, 2005), **para.5.4**: *The equality axioms and non-normal structures*, where the limitations of axioms for equality are discussed.

Comment: I see that definition by the _Theory of Identity_ in mathematical logic and really don't see how to make something sensible out of it without having sort of a representation. If my question sounds like I'm mixing up things, that's just true: I _am_ confused by that _Theory of Identity_. i.e I'm _not_ confused by the numbers $1.000...$ and $0.999...$ as such, but how they are "identified" by logic.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to some useful comments and an answer (and the downvotes)-:
I think now that one of the above definitions is wrong and should be replaced by
the following (also mind the additional '.') :
$$
  P_{c,k}(x) \; :\Longleftrightarrow \; 
  \mbox{" symbol at position $k$ in the decimal representation of $x$ is $c$ "}
  \\ \mbox{where} \quad c \in \{\mbox{'.'},\mbox{'0'},\mbox{'1'},\mbox{'2'},\mbox{'3'},\mbox{'4'},\mbox{'5'},\mbox{'6'},\mbox{'7'},\mbox{'8'},\mbox{'9'}\}
$$
This would mean that the rest of my argument in the question is essentially about
character strings representing the numbers and not about the numbers "themselves".
Then, of course, it's trivial that:
$$
   \mbox{'1.000...'} \ne \mbox{'0.999...'}
$$

**Update.** A nice example of the non-triviality of (non)identity is the following.
Suppose $x$ and $y$ are pictures, like in well known puzzles for children,
when they say "find the differences":

[image]

Instead of a single index $(k)$, a double index $(i,j)$ may be preferred here
for the predicates $P$ :
$$
  P_{i,j}(x) \; :\Longleftrightarrow \; \mbox{"pixel in $x$ at position $(i,j)$ is black"}
$$
The *aspect* $A$ of the identity is *finite* in this case:
$$
 (x \stackrel{A}{=} y) :\Longleftrightarrow
 \left[\;\forall P_{i,j} \in A : P_{i,j}(x) \Longleftrightarrow P_{i,j}(y) \;\right]
$$
It doesn't matter though how many predicates $P$ are actually involved for the
reflexive, symmetric, transitive properties of $\,\stackrel{A}{=}\,$ to hold.
So the above pictures are in fact *always equal in some respect*, even if (quite)
some pixels are *not* the same; just remove the corresponding predicates from the
aspect $A$ and you're done.

Comment: Don't be afraid ... Gottlob Frege, one of the three "biggest" logicians of all times, introduce his fundamental essay on Sense and Reference (Uber Sinn und Bedeutung, 1892) with the following words : "Equality [or identity - in footnote] gives rise to challenging questions not altogether easy to answer. Is it a relation ? A relation between objects or between names or signs of objects ? In my Begriffschrift I assumed the latter."

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA: Thanks! It's not by coincidence that I've put "themselves" between quotes. Because: isn't a predicate about a character in the decimal representation of a number a predicate about the number itself, though indirectly?

Comment: The problem with "trying to be formal" (as mat log do) is that you need to be careful about what you can express with your language and what you can't (e.g.:is it allowed to use an infinetly long string of symbol ?). But you point the finger to an aspect that is (for me) not trivial at all: a formal system is a "language" where you "speak of" something. We assume that the objects that are "speaked of" in the language have some sort of "reality" ; i.e. if we are working with a formalized theory of real numbers, all model of the theory (if any) contains "something" that behave like real numbers.

Comment: It is well known that real numbers are uncountable. But if I can "name" in my system only countable many objects, how I can ... reach, grasp, know ... "them" ? Must we restrict ourselvs to constructive or computable analysis, or use only rational numbers ?